# Google app script - How to create an excel file with multi sheets and attach to MailApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to sending an email from google app script with google sheet file.

For now I can send csv file with multiple file like:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(
    emailList,
    fileName,
    'content',
    {
        attachments: list_attach,
        name: 'Britag Support'
    });
```

with list_attach same

```
[{
  fileName: 'fileName1',
  content: csvTextContent1,
  mimeType:"application//csv"
}, {
  fileName: 'fileName2',
  content: csvTextContent2,
  mimeType:"application//csv"
}]
```

the csvTextContent is a string like:

```
A,B,C\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n...
```

It's create 2 file attach to email. 
Now I want to join 2 above file to one excel file with 2 sheets. How can I do it? Please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to convert 2 CSV files to one Excel file and you want to send an email by including the converted Excel file as an attachment file.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the CSV files from the array object of `list_attach`.
2. Create new Spreadsheet as a temporal.
3. Put the CSV data to the temporal Spreadsheet by parsing the CSV data.
4. Export the temporal Spreadsheet as the blob of Excel format.
5. Delete the temporal Spreadsheet. In this case, that is moved to the trash box.
6. Send an email including the exported Excel data.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(
    emailList,
    fileName,
    'content',
    {
        attachments: list_attach,
        name: 'Britag Support'
    });
```

To:

```
// --- I added blow script
var tempSpreadsheeet = SpreadsheetApp.create("temp");
for (var i = 0; i < list_attach.length; i++) {
  var obj = list_attach[i];
  var values = Utilities.parseCsv(obj.content);
  var sheet = i == 0 ? tempSpreadsheeet.getSheets()[0].setName(obj.fileName) : tempSpreadsheeet.insertSheet().setName(obj.fileName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
var tempId = tempSpreadsheeet.getId();
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=" + tempId;
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getBlob();
blob.setName("sampleFilename.xlsx");
list_attach = [blob];
DriveApp.getFileById(tempId).setTrashed(true);
// ---

MailApp.sendEmail(
    emailList,
    fileName,
    'content',
    {
        attachments: list_attach,
        name: 'Britag Support'
    });
```

#### Note:

- In above modified script, it supposes the following points.

  - `csvTextContent1` and `csvTextContent2` are the CSV data of the string type.
  - The numbers of all columns of CSV data are the same.

If above points are different from your actual data, can you provide the sample values of `csvTextContent1` and `csvTextContent2`? By this, I would like to modify it.

#### References:

- [create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname)
- [parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)
- [setTrashed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: yes, I want do like you said. csvTextContent1 and csvTextContent2 just string text (ex, A,B,C,\n,1,2,3,\n,...). thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Ki Ko Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from your replying. This is due to my  poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. If my sample script cannot resolve your issue, I apologize. When `csvTextContent1` and `csvTextContent2` are `A,B,C,\n,1,2,3,\n,...`, I think that the script works. But if at your actual situation, the script occurs an error, in order to correctly replicate the issue, can you add the sample values of `csvTextContent1` and `csvTextContent2` to your question? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: Awesome. I've replaced obj.content by csvTextContent1. It's working. thank you very much. :). let me update the question

Comment: @Ki Ko Thank you for replying and adding more information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.